# discrete logarithm with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, quaternions

let $z = a + bi$ where $a,b$ are integers on $[0,N)$
let $a + bi \mod t = (a \mod t) + (b \mod t) \cdot i$

Consider the problem of finding $e$ where $z^e \mod N = c$ and $c, N$ and $z$ are known. Is this problem of similar difficulty to the discrete logarithm problem? Could Shor's algorithm be used to solve it. Also, how would the difficulty of this problem change if z were to be a Quaternion or Octonion.

Comment: Is $z$ a Gaussian integer?  Is $t$?  Can you more explicitly define multiplication?

Comment: Right after "Condider the problem..." follows an equation having a capital Z in it. Then it goes on ... where c,N,z are known. Maybe you mean the two z and Z to be the same?

Comment: yes, z is a Gaussian integer and multiplication is defined as it normally is for complex numbers

Comment: sorry about the mixed upper and lower cases. that was not intended